# Need to get actual array_diff in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array say,

```
$a1 = array("19", "20");
$a2 = array("23", "25", "20", "28", "19");
```

I don't know which array contains what but these array values are similar data. Now what i need to get the difference of these two array.

From the Documentation:

```
array array_diff ( array $array1 , array $array2)
```

> array1 The array to compare from
>
> array2 An array to compare against

But my problem is i don't which array contains what values..

**Example 1:**

```
$a1 = array("19", "20");
$a2 = array("23", "25", "20", "28", "19");

print_r(array_diff($a1, $a2)); // Array ( )
```

**Example 2:**

```
$a1 = array("19", "20");
$a2 = array("23", "25", "20", "28", "19");

print_r(array_diff($a2, $a1)); // Array ( [0] => 23 [1] => 25 [3] => 28 )
```

I want the return value as my output whether i use example one or two. Can anyone help me about this issue.

Comment: The question is ambiguous. How similar is the data from your arrays? Does one of them (but you don't know which one) contain all the values of the other? [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) works correctly. Do you want to get the elements that are not in both arrays? There are many [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) that can help you, given you express your goal clearly.

Comment: No i don't mean other things that you may understand, In my problem i need to get the difference of the array's, But in function there are the bindings that i have to use all values in first array and some values in second array. So if i don't know which array contain most values than how can i decide to use as first array???

Answer (score 3):

You can use `array_intersect` to get which values are alike, then use `array_diff` on the merge of the two arrays:

```
$a1 = array("19", "20");
$a2 = array("23", "25", "20", "28", "19");

$a3 = array_diff(array_merge($a1, $a2), array_intersect($a1,$a2));

print_r($a3);
```

Comment: This is looks good, but similar to the @user1234 's answer, but has the explanation and well structured.

Answer (score 2):

You can do both and combine them in an `array_merge()`

```
$difference = array_merge(array_diff($a2, $a1), array_diff($a1, $a2));
```

Comment: Yes i just want to to get the actual difference that are not abstract when i use in different order.

Comment: Yep that will do it no matter the order.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
  <?php
   $a1 = array("19", "20");
   $a2 = array("23", "25", "20", "28", "19");
    $result = array_intersect($a1, $a2);// will give you commoon values
    $whole = array_merge($a1,$a2);// merge both array
    $new = array_diff($whole,$result);// will give values which are not in any one array either $a1 or $a2
 echo "<pre>";  print_r($new);
    ?>
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [2] => 23
    [3] => 25
    [5] => 28
)
```

Answer (score -1):

It seems you're trying to do an array_diff between the biggest and the smallest array, not knowing which is which, here is a way :

```
$big = array();
$small = array();
if(count($a1) > count($a2)){
    $big = $a1;
    $small = $a2;
}
else{
    $big = $a2;
    $small = $a1;
}

print_r(array_diff($big, $small));
```

Comment: `count($a1) > $a2` is always `FALSE` but it's wrong anyway.

Comment: I corrected my mistake. Why would it be wrong anyway ?

Comment: The size of the array is no indicator for which diff will result in an empty array. (Unless it is, because there are some specific restrictions on OP's scenario…)

Comment: I agree with the fact that the size of the array is not an indicator. But it might be (it happened to me). That's why I felt it was worth mentionning.